# Hibernate using deafult dialect instead of dialect from application.properties

Tags: mysql, spring, database, hibernate, jpa

I'm using spring boot + jpa + hibernate. There is my application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8nnoDBDialect
  
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/nodramazone
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

But in logs I see default dialect:

```
org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Comment: I fixed it by adding:

@PropertySource("file:src/main/resources/application.properties")

To DataLoader class

Comment: Hrrmm it should automatically be looking for your properties file in that directory... Do you have a class where you are manually configuring the property file locations?

Answer (score 1):

The property name is wrong. Instead of `spring.jpa.database-platform` you have to use `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect`

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8nnoDBDialect
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# MySQL
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
#spring.datasource.username=dbuser
#spring.datasource.password=dbpass
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Comment: still
HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

Comment: Is application.properties being read? Did you put it in the resources folder?

Comment: It is in resources

Comment: Edited the answer. Try that

Comment: I tried to sout value of property in run() and i got something like this:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataLoader': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect' in value "${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect}"

Comment: It didn't help. I think spring doesnt see my properties file